# Javascript and prototyping procedure

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I am trying to write a script that does a slide show. I can do it with functions, but I want to use the prototype method. What I am having a hard time figuring out is the procedure. Here is what I have tried to do

```
var displayVars = {
    slide: '',
    thumb: ''   
}

//setup display
display = function(slide,thumb) {

    displayVars.slide = $(slide);

    displayVars.thumb = $(thumb);

    // set slider width
}

display.prototype.play = function() {

    // move slide to this location

    display.hightlight();
}

display.prototype.hightlight = function() {

    // add border to element
}

$(function() {

    newdis = new display('.show-slide','.window-thumbs');

    displayVars.timer = setTimeout(newdis.play,500);

});
```

If you notice in the play function I want to call the highlight method. What I really want is to run the highlight function every time the play function is called. I can't get my head to see how this can be done because "display" or "this" will not let me access the highlight function.

Comment: `this` will indeed let you call the "highlight" function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the innards of your prototype functions, but rather with the way you set up the timeout handler.

```
displayVars.timer = setTimeout(function() { newdis.play(); }, 500);
```

Then you'll be able to use `this` in the "play" function:

```
display.prototype.play = function() {

  // move slide to this location

  this.hightlight();
}
```

There's no intrinsic "membership" relationship between a function and an object of any sort. Object properties can refer to functions, but the only time that means anything is when a function call is made via the object property reference. Since you weren't *calling* the function, but just grabbing a reference to it to pass to "setTimeout()", there was nothing to set the value of `this`.  By wrapping it in an anonymous function that explicitly calls "play" via the object reference, you set up `this` correctly.

Another way to do this is with the "bind()" function available in newer browsers:

```
displayVars.tinmer = setTimeout(newdis.play.bind(newdis), 500);
```

That will have more-or-less the same effect as the anonymous function (with some extra subtleties that don't make much difference most of the time).

Comment: Thank you so much I spent hours trying for figure this out.